# MariaDB are bitwise operators defined on strings?

Tags: mariadb, string, operator, bit-manipulation

Is the behavior of `BITAND`, (*bitwise and*) defined in MariaDB over strings?

```
SELECT '0011' & '0011', 'ff' & 'ff', 'yy' & 'YY', '5' & '5';
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| '0011' & '0011' | 'ff' & 'ff' | 'yy' & 'YY' | '5' & '5' |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|              11 |           0 |           0 |         5 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I'm just wondering what is exactly happening here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that MariaDB (and MySQL for that matter) attempts to implicitly cast operands of bitwise operators to integers, and it is known MySQL behaviour when converting strings to integers to ignore the rest of the string if it encounters non-digits, e.g. `cast('123abc' as integer)` will yield integer 123, and `cast('ff' as integer)` will yield 0.

This is a feature of the bitwise operators and bit functions, not the `BIT` type itself, as stated in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html) (I assume MariaDB inherits this behaviour):

> Currently, bit functions and operators require BIGINT (64-bit integer) arguments and return BIGINT values, so they have a maximum range of 64 bits. Arguments of other types are converted to BIGINT and truncation might occur.

It looks like this behaviour is going to change in MySQL version 8:

> An extension for MySQL 8.0 changes this cast-to-BIGINT behavior: Bit functions and operators permit binary string type arguments (BINARY, VARBINARY, and the BLOB types), enabling them to take arguments and produce return values larger than 64 bits.

which will bring it in line with your expectations.

Comment: so do mysql not have bit-types at all, is that just a veneer for an int type?

Comment: It looks like so

Comment: @EvanCarroll you can't say they don't have the bit data type, because [they do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html). Implementation may not be up to your standards, I realize that.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to have a bit type if the operators treat it like an int, and it's stored as an int?

Comment: @EvanCarroll 